# Check if email is already activated not working

Tags: php, mysql, session

I just created a script that is checking if the user has already activated his account. If so, it should say "The account has already been activated" and if not then activate that account. The problem is it always says "Activation was successful." Can someone help me please?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$dbconnect = mysqli_connect('server', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
if (isset($_GET['status']) && (strlen($_GET['status']) == 32)) {
    $status = $_GET['status'];
}

if (isset($email) && isset($status)) {

    $sql = "SELECT status FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result == 'active') {

        echo" <div style='position:absolute;left:29.5%;top:10%;width:41%;' class='alert alert-danger'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>Chyba!</strong> &#218;&#269;et je ji&#158; aktivov&#225;n!
             </div>";
    } else {

        $query_activate_account = "UPDATE users SET status='active' WHERE(email ='$email' AND status='$status')";
        $result_activate_account = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query_activate_account);

        echo" <div style='position:absolute;left:29.5%;top:10%;width:41%;' class='alert alert-success'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>ĂšspÄ›ch!</strong> Aktivace probÄ›hla ĂşspÄ›ĹˇnÄ›! <a href='signin.php'>PĹ™ihlĂˇĹˇenĂ­</a>
             </div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli functions

Comment: Your query is open to SQL Injection. You need to sanitze your user input before you use it in any query or preferably, use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update

```
 $sql = "SELECT status FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
to 
 $sql = "SELECT status FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result )){
  $status = $row['status'];
}
```

And replace

```
if ($result == 'active') {
```

with

```
if ($status== 'active') {
```

Comment: It said: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /data/web/virtuals/115709/virtual/www/activate.php on line 17

Comment: I added $result on $sql, please see my updated answer...done

Comment: The solution should be mysqli and fix injection attack vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working perfectly.

Comment: Dude!!! add your answer and stop commenting negativity pls...done

Comment: @iWispy please accept my answer. You welcome...done

Comment: I will accept your answer, but I have to wait 2 more minutes.